# How to make tunnels in websocket which will be distinguishable?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, server

How to make that on the front-end were sent to a particular user only the data relating to him, because currently when I log on to several users, the message is broadcast to all logged on and should be to specific people, ie, to be identified connections between the server -> user. ie, I want to send for example 1 to user1 2 to user2 3 to user3 . "hello" to user100 and so on. Different messages to different users.
server:

```
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');

    // Create HTTP server
    const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
    });

    // Create WebSocket server and attach it to the HTTP server
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

    // Handle WebSocket connections
    wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
      console.log('Client connected');

      eventEmitter.on('data', (userId, message) => {
        
        console.log('Connected user:', userId);
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ userId, message }));
      });
      // Handle WebSocket messages
      ws.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log('Received message from client:', message);
      });
    
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', err);
  });
```

frontend:

```
const ID = window.location.pathname.split('/')[3];
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');   
    
   
    ws.onopen = () => {
        console.log('Connected TO WS SERVER');
    };
      
    ws.onmessage = (event) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data); // Parsowanie danych z JSON
        console.log('Message from server:', data);
        console.log('Message for current user:', data.message);
    
        var exampleMsg = {
            date: "2024-03-07T12:34:56Z",
            value: parseInt(data.message)
        };
        handleSocketData(lineChart1, exampleMsg);
```